# Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for OBJECT Map<String, Map<Object,Long>>

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, hashmap

I'm trying to create a Map> in Java app, but when trying to deserialize I'm having the next error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for Object (start marker at [Source: (String)"{"number":10000000,"person":{"person1":{"{\"Name\":\"test\", \"userId\":\"test1\", \"requestDate\":null}":2222}}}"; line: 1, column: 106])


 at [Source: (String)"{"number":10000000,"person":{"test":{"{\"Name\":\"test\", \"userId\":\"test1\", \"requestDate\":null}":2222}}}"; line: 1, column: 191] (through reference chain: com.mycompany.mavenproject1.testClass["person"])
```

I have created an object and add data into it. After that I map it to String:

```
String personTest = map.writeValueAsString(myObject);
```

This is the String it generates:

```
{"number":10000000,"person":{"test":{"{\"Name\":\"test\", \"userId\":\"test1\", \"requestDate\":null}":2222}}}
```

And I am trying to deserialize it as:

```
testClass t2 = map.readValue(personTest , testClass.class);
```

Where the TestClass is the next:

```
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class testClass implements Serializable{
    private final long number;

    @JsonDeserialize(contentUsing=ExampleClassJsonDeserializer.class)
    private Map<String, Map<Person, Long>> person;

    public testClass(){
        keepAliveTimeout = 10000000;
        person = new HashMap();
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess there is the issue with the JSON string please verify it once {"number":10000000,
 "person":{
   "test":[
     {"Name":"test", 
      "userId":"test1", 
      "requestDate":null}
     ]}} 
i have made some change in that and now it looks fine

Comment: @AshishSharma the String is taked from String personTest = map.writeValueAsString(t);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As amanin suggested it can be done by customizing serializer and deserializer.

But finally the simplest solution was to serialize the Object to bytes[] and encoding it to Base64. So isn't necessary to write custom Serializer or Deserializer.

The following code works for me:

*Encode*

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
oos.writeObject(testObject);
oos.flush();
byte [] testObjectBytes = bos.toByteArray();
String testObjectString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(testObjectBytes);
```

*Decode*

```
byte[] decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(testObjectString);
ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(decoded);
is = new ObjectInputStream(in);
testObject = (testClass)is.readObject();
```

Answer (score 0):

You probem comes from the the fact that your map keys are Person object, not simple string.

There's not enough code posted for me to *precisely* pinpoint the problem, but somehow, Jackson tried to create JSON field name from a Person object, by writing the Person object JSON, then making it a label. The consequence is a disaster : Json injection in field names.

You either have to customize your serializer to extract a simple string from your person object to make a field name, or change the structure to replace :

```java
Map<String, Map<Person, Long>> person;
```

with something Jackson can handle without customization (so, where field names are assured to be simple labels):

```java
class PersonWithLong { public Person; public Long value}
Map<String, Set<PersonWithLong>> person;
```